# Statistics inquiry

Tags: java, statistics, apache-commons-math

How do I obtain critical T values?

Using apache stat I can't seem to get the values?

For instance

```
Tdistribution t= new Tdistribution(10);
t.CumulativeProbabilty(0.05);//alpha=0.O5
```

if you look in table values are different.

Comment: 1. cumulativeProbability computes the CDF, i.e. the input is a t-value and the output is a P-value. You are looking for the opposite, i.e. the input is a P-value and the output is a t-value. This is called the inverse CDF and looking at the docs, it appears that apahe-commons-math doesn't do it.

Comment: 2. Most tables for critical t-values are for two-sided tests. That means that it gives you the t-value for which P(t' < -t) + P(t' > t) = P. The t distribution is symmetric, so that's the same as 2 P (t' < -t) = P. So once you find an inverseCumulativeProbability method, you want -inverseCumulativeProbability(P / 2) to match the table value.

Comment: @DavidWright, I could seriously kiss you right now! 
That detailed explanation was exactly what I needed for my statistic project.
Thank you, I think this should be the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you might be interpreting the values of the t-table incorrectly.

Take for example the exercise proposed [here](http://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/how-to-use-the-t-table-to-solve-statistics-problems/):

> A t-value of 2.35, from a t-distribution with 14 degrees of freedom,
>   has an upper-tail (“greater than”) probability between which two
>   values on the t-table? Answer: 0.025 and 0.01 Using the t-table,
>   locate the row with 14 degrees of freedom and look for 2.35. However,
>   this exact value doesn’t lie in this row, so look for the values on
>   either side of it: 2.14479 and 2.62449. [...]

If you try to solve this with `apache-commons-math` you get the following,

```
TDistribution t = new TDistribution(14);
System.out.println(1- t.cumulativeProbability(2.35));

0.016981716091246768
```

which is ok with the results, however more accurate. 0.016 is indeed between 0.025 and 0.01.

If you want to get straight a value of the t-table, like for example probability with 10 degrees of freedom and a t-value of 1.812461, the answer is

```
t = new TDistribution(10);
System.out.println(1- t.cumulativeProbability(1.812461));

0.050000010018874885
```

while the probability value in the table is 0.5

*EDIT* after comments:
In order to calculate the quantile, you have to use `inverseCumulativeProbability`. This is in the abstract class `AbstractRealDistribution`.

```
System.out.println(t.inverseCumulativeProbability(0.95));
1.8124611228157772
```

Comment: Um trying to implement something like t(.05,10)=some value.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer. If you still have issues pls let me know.